# Extracting diagonal of $J^TJ$ via automatic differentiation like techniques

Tags: derivatives, numerical-optimization, chain-rule

First of all please, let me know if this question is more suited for `scicomp.stackexchange.com` or `or.stackexchange.com`, and sorry for my English and math skills.

Pretty often i do some numerical optimization stuff with Gauss-Newton and automatic differentiation. It's pretty handy because Gauss-Newton requires to solve following system:
$$
J^TJ\Delta x = -J^Tr
$$
where $r(x)$ is residuals function, $J$ is jacobian of $r$, $\Delta x$ is step. 
This system can be solved via Conjugate gradient method which requires $Av$ like products. Automatic differentiation allow me to compute $Jv$ and $J^Tv$ via forward and reverse mode of graph based automatic differentiation, so i can easily combine it with CG.

Unfortunately CG also needs preconditioner for fast convergence. Obvious choice for preconditioner is diagonal of $J^TJ$.

My question is - how can i quickly compute diagonal of $J^TJ$ if i know expression graph for $r$ and have implementation of $J^Tv$ and $Jv$ for each elementary function? Without symbolic differentiation, if it possible.

Answer (score 3):

A recent paper:

Siskind, Jeffrey Mark. "Automatic Differentiation: Inverse Accumulation Mode." (2019).

should solve your problem.  You can efficiently apply the inverse Jacobian and its transpose to the right side.

Comment: This is interesting, but only applies to the case where $J$ is square and invertible. In practice $J$ is typically rectangular

Comment: @NickAlger Good thinking.  However, I don't believe that the inverted Jacobian products calculated in the paper rely on a square Jacobian.  After all, the non-inverted Jacobian products have no such constraint.

Comment: They do mention the requirement that the matrix be square in the last sentence of the first paragraph of the paper. In the rectangular case maybe one could still apply their algorithm and get something, but I would be very skeptical. At the core, that is trying to invert a non-invertible map.

Comment: @NickAlger Yeah, you are probably more of an expert than I am.  That said, they say that the matrix should be square for the problem to be "well posed".  Could it be possible that it ends up working out to something like a product with the *Moore–Penrose inverse* of the Jacobian?  If you have any insights, please share.